# Shell, column -t, treat everything after Nth space as a last column

Tags: bash, shell, formatting

I want to print a two column table. In the first column are paths (without spaces), in the second column are names (with spaces). I'd like to make the `column` treat everything after Nth space (N = 2) as belonging to a single column.

I don't need to use the `column`, but I'd like something short.
Note: I'm not looking for other solution that expects that there are only two columns.

```
mark@localhost ~/.config/chromium/Default/Extensions
% for f in */*/manifest.json; do
    echo -n "$f ";
    cat $f | jq -r '.name + " " + .version';
done | column -t
cjpalhdlnbpafiamejdnhcphjbkeiagm/1.14.22_0/manifest.json     uBlock                  Origin      1.14.22          
dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb/1.62.4_0/manifest.json      Vimium                  1.62.4                       
dffhipnliikkblkhpjapbecpmoilcama/0.3_0/manifest.json         Swap                    My          Cookies  0.3     
gcbommkclmclpchllfjekcdonpmejbdp/2017.12.6_0/manifest.json   __MSG_about_ext_name__  2017.12.6                    
gdbofhhdmcladcmmfjolgndfkpobecpg/4.19_0/manifest.json        Don't                   track       me       Google  4.19
pkehgijcmpdhfbdbbnkijodmdjhbjlgp/2017.11.20_0/manifest.json  __MSG_name__            2017.11.20
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To take the output of some `command` (which could be your loop) and format it with everything after the first two spaces as being part of one column:

```
command | sed 's/ /\t/g; s/\t/ /2; s/\t/ /1' input | column -ts' ' | sed 's/\t/ /g'
```

As an example, consider this file as input:

```
$ cat input
c1 c2 Eric Clapton
column1 column2 David Crosby
very-long-first-column 2nd Jimi Hendrix Jr
```

We can generate your desired output via:

```
$ sed 's/ /\t/g; s/\t/ /2; s/\t/ /1' input | column -ts' ' | sed 's/\t/ /g'
c1                      c2       Eric Clapton
column1                 column2  David Crosby
very-long-first-column  2nd      Jimi Hendrix Jr
```

#### How it works

We work on the text in three steps:

1. `sed 's/ /\t/g; s/\t/ /2; s/\t/ /1'`

   This replaces all blanks except the first two with tabs.
2. `column -ts' '`

   This does `column -t` formatting but applies it only to blank-separated fields.
3. `sed 's/\t/ /g'`

   This converts the tabs in the third column back to blanks.

#### Shell function for ease-of-use

First, define:

```
format() { sed 's/ /\t/g; s/\t/ /2; s/\t/ /1' "$@" | column -ts' ' | sed 's/\t/ /g'; }
```

Now, we can apply the formatting in a quick-and-simple way, either as part of a pipeline:

```
$ cat input | format
c1                      c2       Eric Clapton
column1                 column2  David Crosby
very-long-first-column  2nd      Jimi Hendrix Jr
```

Or, operating on a file:

```
$ format input
c1                      c2       Eric Clapton
column1                 column2  David Crosby
very-long-first-column  2nd      Jimi Hendrix Jr
```

To make the definition of `format` permanent, place it in your `~/.bashrc` file.

#### Formatting for N number of columns

Let's define a function that will allow us to specify a number of columns:

```
frmt() { [[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] && sed "s/ /\t/$1g" "${@:2}" | column -ts' ' | sed 's/\t/ /g'; }
```

We can format a file for two columns:

```
$ frmt 2 input
c1                      c2 Eric Clapton
column1                 column2 David Crosby
very-long-first-column  2nd Jimi Hendrix Jr
```

Or for 3 columns:

```
$ frmt 3 input
c1                      c2       Eric Clapton
column1                 column2  David Crosby
very-long-first-column  2nd      Jimi Hendrix Jr
```

We can use the same function as part of a pipeline:

```
$ cat input | frmt 3
c1                      c2       Eric Clapton
column1                 column2  David Crosby
very-long-first-column  2nd      Jimi Hendrix Jr
```

This approach uses GNU sed and, consequently, will work on Linux, including ArchLinux, but not on OSX/BSD systems.

Comment: Thank you, but that's too long and horrible. Not really for quick one-liners.

Comment: Are you familiar with shell functions?  (They make "long and horrible" into short and quick.)

Comment: I said in the original post that I'm not interested in solutions that expect only 2 columns. I'm looking for something generic, that can be used quickly when needed, not limited to the format of data I posted. I was hoping that there's a smarter `column` alternative.

Comment: What OS are you using?  (Yes, it makes a difference.)

Comment: I'm using ArchLinux.

Comment: @MarkHoward See updated answer for arbitrary number of columns.

Comment: @Sundeep You are absolutely right.  Thanks!  Name changed.

Comment: Wow, the `frmt` function is really nice hack! I think it'd be better if the `column` supported it by default but your function is just what I'd like to use. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
command | sed 's/[^ ]*/&\t/' | column -ts $'\t'
```